# Count the number of records active between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, intervals, between

I am trying to do a query to retreive the number of active calls for a given time,

I have a table CALLS with all the calls record with an AnsweredTime and ReleaseTime and I need to retrieve the number of calls active for every second during the day.

So I've done the following  :

```
    SELECT dt,
(SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Calls WHERE
    AnsweredTimestamp <= dt AND
    ReleasedTimestamp >= dt)
 FROM CALView
WHERE dt >='2011-10-05'
and dt <'2011-10-06'
```

CalView is a table containing every second between two dates

The query return this (partialy) :

```
2011-10-05 09:40:00.000 20
2011-10-05 09:40:01.000 20
2011-10-05 09:40:02.000 20
2011-10-05 09:40:03.000 21
2011-10-05 09:40:04.000 21
2011-10-05 09:40:05.000 21
2011-10-05 09:40:06.000 21
2011-10-05 09:40:07.000 21
2011-10-05 09:40:08.000 21
2011-10-05 09:40:09.000 21
2011-10-05 09:40:10.000 20
2011-10-05 09:40:11.000 20
2011-10-05 09:40:12.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:13.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:14.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:15.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:16.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:17.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:18.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:19.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:20.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:21.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:22.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:23.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:24.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:25.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:26.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:27.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:28.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:29.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:30.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:31.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:32.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:33.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:34.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:35.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:36.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:37.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:38.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:39.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:40.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:41.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:42.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:43.000 18
2011-10-05 09:40:44.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:45.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:46.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:47.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:48.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:49.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:50.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:51.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:52.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:53.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:54.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:55.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:56.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:57.000 19
2011-10-05 09:40:58.000 20
2011-10-05 09:40:59.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:00.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:01.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:02.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:03.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:04.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:05.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:06.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:07.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:08.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:09.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:10.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:11.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:12.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:13.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:14.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:15.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:16.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:17.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:18.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:19.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:20.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:21.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:22.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:23.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:24.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:25.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:26.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:27.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:28.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:29.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:30.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:31.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:32.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:33.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:34.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:35.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:36.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:37.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:38.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:39.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:40.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:41.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:42.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:43.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:44.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:45.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:46.000 18
2011-10-05 09:41:47.000 18
2011-10-05 09:41:48.000 19
2011-10-05 09:41:49.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:50.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:51.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:52.000 20
2011-10-05 09:41:53.000 20
```

So I got the good result but the query is extremly slow, I've done the indexing, I am just wondering if there is something more I can do..

Comment: Select statements within select statements never preform well.  lemme rewrite

Comment: Are you sure CalView is not a view? If that is the case, performance is going to be quite bad.

Comment: @luis - it's a simple table that contains 1 row for every second in a 24 hour clock I assume.  Doubtful given his setup that it's actually a view.

Answer (score 6):

It's an interesting cartesian that you'll create here.

```
Select dt,count(1)
from calview
left join calls on calls.AnsweredTimestamp <= calview.dt AND
                    calls.ReleasedTimestamp >= calview.dt
WHERE dt >='2011-10-05'
and dt <'2011-10-06'
group by dt
```

I believe this should give you one row for every second a call is active...then it's a simple count. Hoping my syntax is correct, I don't have a ms sql server environment to confirm on.

ETA: Left join was used so any seconds with 0 calls will appear on here with a null count.  If you switch to an inner join, the row will disappear for that 1 second interval.

Comment: You've got me curious--I'm assuming this is for call centre reporting--what is your business looking for in 1 second interval call reports that couldn't be determined by...say 5 second interval reports?  10?  The less rows in your calls table, the faster this will run...you've got 86k rows per day and a nondedicated server will struggle on this.  If you have a good machine to run this on, then great...wanna try it to the millisecond level for the fun of it?  If not, fewer intervals will speed this up and I'm not sure what more you'd see on a per second level like this.